# How do you convert ImageMagick command line options to MiniMagick for use in CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, carrierwave, minimagick

I tried to convert this command line option to a processor method to use in carrierwave but I couldn't get it to work.  I was following the [method I saw here](http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/CarrierWave/MiniMagick.html).

```
convert E22725-89PC.jpg -matte -fill none -fuzz 15% -opaque white result.png
```

Here is my CarrierWave uploader

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  process :remove_background => 'white'

  def remove_background(color)
    manipulate! do |img|
      img = img.format 'png'
      img = img.matte
      img = img.fill 'none'
      img = img.fuzz '15%'
      img = img.opaque color
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Yeah, `NoMethodError: undefined method `matte' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like your method should be [mattecolor](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=es52ar3uvqnue5rok5kbda5gb6#mattecolor)

But that doesn't account for the nil:NilClass.

I wonder if you have to include ImageMagick in your uploader.

> manipulate!()
>
> Manipulate the image with RMagick. This method will load up an image
>   and then pass each of its frames to the supplied block. It will then
>
> > save the image to disk.
>
> **Gotcha**
>
> This method assumes that the object responds to current_path. Any
>   class that this module is mixed into must have a current_path method.
>   CarrierWave::Uploader does, so you won’t need to worry about this in
>   most cases.

http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/CarrierWave/MiniMagick.html#M000063

Comment: matte is a different option but the way they have MiniMagick in the example doesn't work for me using those options.

Comment: I guess I didn't write that clearly. Matte was not among the methods available on the command-line options referenced by the mini-magick extension. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=es52ar3uvqnue5rok5kbda5gb6

Comment: Did you try including ImageMagick in your uploader?